# Use absolute path for .jsx files?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to make the import file paths in my react app absolute.

(**EDIT:** I'm trying to make this:

```
import fetchAPI from "../../util/api"
```

to this

```
import fetchAPI from "util/api"
```

)

I've seen solutions to this by using the jsconfig.json as such

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

The way I understand it, this only makes the file paths in .js files absolute. Unfortunately the wide majority of the files in the project are .jsx, is there a way to make the file paths in these absolute?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am also wondering how to achieve this.

Comment: I was using Gatsby so the plugin: "gatsby-plugin-resolve-src" did it for me in the end :)

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to change the `target` option to `"target": "esnext"`.

And change the
`compilerOption` to target React or react-native like `"jsx": "preserve"` or `"jsx": "react"` or `"jsx": "react-native"`.

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "jsx": "react",
    "baseUrl": "src"
},
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/node_modules/*"
]
```

}